# Typescript generic function to get total from list of objects

Tags: typescript, generics, typeguards

I'm writing generic function to get a total obj based on the list:

```
export function getTotal<T extends { [key: string]: number | unknown }>(
  list: T[]
): T | null {
  if (list.length === 0) return null;
  if (list.length === 1) return list[0];

  return list.reduce((acc: T, item: T) => {
    acc = { ...acc };

    const keys = Object.keys(item) as Array<keyof T>;

    keys.forEach((key: keyof T) => {
      if (typeof item[key] === 'number' && typeof acc[key] === 'number') {
        // TODO: check why this is not working
        // acc[key] = item[key] + acc[key];
        const a: number = item[key] as number;
        const b: number = acc[key] as number;
        const sum: any = a + b;

        acc[key] = sum;
      } else {
        acc[key] = item[key];
      }
    });

    return acc;
  });
}
```

the idea is - any object prop which is numeric should be added as sum result, and any text/non-numeric should be kept as is.
Problem is that simple addition `acc[key] = item[key] + acc[key];` is failing
`Operands of '+' operation must either be one of string, number, bigint or any (if allowed by option)eslint@typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands` 
and if the type guard is ignored

The workaround with any looks ugly,

```
       keys.forEach((key: keyof T) => {
        const a = item[key];
        const b = acc[key];

        if (typeof a === 'number' && typeof b === 'number') {
          // TODO: check why this is not working
          // acc[key] = item[key] + acc[key];
          const sum: any = a + b;

          acc[key] = sum;
        } else {
          acc[key] = item[key];
        }
      });
```

partially works, but still have to use any casting

So - to surmise - the questions are both:

1. Why type guard `if (typeof item[key] === 'number' && typeof acc[key] === 'number') {` is not allowing to work with acc[key] as a number
2. How to make it work without the use of `any` casting

Comment: What is your question here, exactly?  Is it "why is this happening" or "how can I write this differently"?  They are related but distinct questions.  For the former one problem is  that `T[K]` might be *narrower* than `number` so you can't necessarily claim that `acc[key]+item[key]` will be assignable to it.  Another issue is type guarding on nonliteral keys doesn't work as described in [ms/TS#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530).  If you want to fix it you can do something like [this](//tsplay.dev/mbE19N) but assertions are still needed for lhs.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explicitly as a clear well-defined question, and then let me know if you want me to write up any of the above as an answer, or if I'm missing somehting.

Comment: Please [edit] this to ask a *single* primary question, or it risks being closed with "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."